# Injecting Spring bean into Camel DSL

Tags: java, spring, osgi, apache-camel

Trying to add Spring bean to Camel body property. 
Something like:

```
MVEL: exchange.in.body.limit = uiLimit
<transform>
    <mvel>
        exchange.in.body.limit = uiLimit;
        exchange.in.body;
    </mvel>
</transform>
Spel: request.body.limit = uiLimit
```

Or even putting in header first:

```
<setHeader headerName="limit">
  <simple>ref:uiLimit</simple>
</setHeader>
```

Where uiLimit is:

```
<bean id="uiLimit" class="java.math.BigInteger">
  <constructor-arg value="${UI_LIMIT} />
</bean>
```

And still getting null in header and property.

Any ideas why bean lookup in Registry doesn't work for OSGI? (all beans/routes inside single bundle)

PS: this works fine in Route:

```
<bean ref="uiLimit" method="toString"/>
```

Comment: What is ${UI_LIMIT}, is it a property? And, in last code-block, 2 closing quotes are missing ;-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Quotes added. ${UI_LIMIT} is a property (String)

Answer (score 1):

The `transform` is only for transforming the message body. Not to mutate headers.

If you want to change a header, use `setHeader`

Comment: I have described 3 ways to find Spring bean in Registry. 
1. Via Simple and setHeader 
2. Via Mvel 
3. Via Spel 
None of them is working in OSGI environment

Answer (score 0):

The reason of such behaviour is that Exchange created in another bundle and came via exposed service:

```
<osgi:service ref="someHandler" interface="org.apache.camel.Component"/>
```

Exchange contains Registry/Context from another bundle where this bean is not declared.
All expression languages are working with Registry/Context attached to Exchange and not with Registry of current budle